# Active-X control fails to load in web page

Tags: mfc, activex, atl

I followed the instructions given in this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/167158 for packing my ActiveX control. It works fine in my development machine. When it is accessed in some other machine it gives the following error "Windows Has blocked this software because it cant verify the publisher". I have used a test certificate to sign my control and the testing machine is Windows 7 with IE 9.

**Problem Fixed:**

I have to sign my .ocx file other than my cab file and build the control with MFC dlls statically linked. That helped me to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some options:

1. Sign the CAB
2. Add your site to trusted site or change your browser settings

Here some links about signing the CAB:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537364(v=vs.85).aspx - Signing and Checking Code with Authenticode
http://www.top20toolbar.com/misc/codesigncert.htm - Article about how to sign ActiveX for free
you can also try to install the activeX with non-admin rights (Only for vista and Windows 7) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369519(v=vs.85).aspx - Installing a Package with Elevated Privileges for a Non-Admin

What about Download unsigned ActiveX set to Enable:

[image]

if this is working then you need to check your sign and see it's ok,

[image]

Comment: I signed it with test certificate and i even added the site to trusted sites and changed my browser setting to   Run ActiveX and plug-ins – Enabled
 
o   Download Signed ActiveX Control – Enabled
 
o   Script ActiveX controls marked as safe for scripting – Enabled

Comment: I tried this also but failed. I have created a self certificate using makecert tool. What i have tried is i ran the code using vs2008 then it worked. May be VS is regestering itself. Wondering how to do it through cab